# How can I create a shape made up of dried herbs & spices?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, brush

I am trying to create a shape out of dried herbs & spices (like oregano), and I want the texture to look similar to this image:

[image: Dried herbs]

I tried looking for dried herbs brushes and actions but can't find any.

Any ideas or suggestions of how to approach this? I want the final effect to have a very realistic effect (with all the little tiny pieces around the shape). So I want it to look like the shape was created in real life from actual spices.

Comment: It would be much easier and take *far* less time to simply use herbs and set up a photo shoot.

Comment: to further Scott's comment, you could print a very light version of the logo and "color it" with clear adhesive, then apply the herbs. The bulk of the logo would be well formed and then you can "deckle the edges" in a more freeform manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a brush that has the inside texture of a lot of herbs and the edges of fewer herbs.

[Here's a tutorial](http://www.obsidiandawn.com/creating-photoshop-brushes-tutorial) if you don't know how to create a brush

And here's a very rough and badly done example of how you should build the brush:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could create an image in Photoshop with the clone tool by copying and cloning a small area of the photograph you posted, and build up your idea from that, but in my opinion it would be easier and more professional looking to create the shape with real oregano on a white table top and take a photograph of it. You could then tweak it a little in Photoshop to get the desired result.